# Suppress numbering for newcommand and contional mesh up of text

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have two questions. First I would like to add subsection to the tableofcontent of my document to structure a little bit the toc without repeating the subsection in the docoment. And I already found out that this code:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{longtable}

% NEW CODE FOR THE PROBLEM!!!
\newcommand{\fakesubsection}[1]{%
  \subsectionmark{#1}% Add subsection mark (header)
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}% Add subsection to ToC
  % Add more content here, if needed.
}
\tableofcontents


\section{Header A}
\fakesubsection{subsection}
\input{site1.tex}
\input{site2.tex}
\input{site3.tex}

\section{Header B}
\input{site1.tex}
\input{site2.tex}
\input{site3.tex}

\end{document}
```

works for me but now I would like to suppress the numbering of the subsections and I didn't find a solution for this problem that's why I am hopping someone here can give me a hint how I can do this.

My second question can I use something like conditional meshed for the text so that every entry that start after a section a meshed up 2 cm and every entry that starts after a subsection 4 cm so that I get a structure like

```
Header AAA
  Subsection aaa
    Site 1
    Site 2
    Site 3

Header BBB
  Site 4
  Site 5
  Site 6
```

I hope my explation is good enough to understand what I am looking for and of course I would very thankful for every hint.
best regards
Dan

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do not post two different (and apparently totally unrelated) issues in one question.

Comment: If you want to remove the numbering, just remove the `\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}` code snippet in `\addcontentsline`

Comment: Crosspost: http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?77109

Answer (score 3):

`scrartcl` is a KOMA-Script class. So you can use

```
\newcommand{\fakesubsection}[1]{%
  \subsectionmark{#1}% add subsection mark (header)
  \addsubsectiontocentry{}{#1}% add as subsection to ToC
}
```

to add this text as subsection without number to the table of contents.

---

**Update** using `scrreprt` which provides chapters (based on the MWE and the informations in [this post on mrunix.de](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?77109))

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}[2016/05/10]

% Inputencoding hier selbst festlegen
\PreventPackageFromLoading{inputenc,fixltx2e}
\usepackage{cook}% see https://sourceforge.net/projects/chilicookbook/
\UnPreventPackageFromLoading{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{longtable}

\recipecolor{C20E0F}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsectiontocdepth}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  beforeskip=-2cm,%
  font=\rmfamily\Huge\color{darkred},%
  tocentryformat=\sffamily\Large\textbf%
]{chapter}
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  tocbeforeskip=5pt plus .2pt,%
  toclinefill=\hfill,%
  tocpagenumberformat=\blank,%
  tocentryformat=\textbf%
]{section}
\newcommand\blank[1]{}

\newcommand{\fakesection}[1]{%
  \sectionmark{#1}% Add subsection mark (header)
  \addtocentrydefault{section}{}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Hauptgericht}
\fakesection{Deutsche Küche}
\begin{recipe}[]{Bandnudeln mit Lachs}{Quelle?}{}
  \ingredient{Salz, Pfeffer}
  \ingredient{Bandnudeln}
  \step
  Ins Restaurant gehen und kaufen, essen und freuen
\end{recipe}

\begin{recipe}[]{Apfelpfannkuchen}{Quelle?}{}
  \ingredient{2 Äpfel}
  \ingredient{Prise Salz}
  \step
  Chips sind auch lecker
\end{recipe}

\chapter{Gebäck}
\begin{recipe}[]{Apfel-Zimt-Muffins}{Quelle?}{}
  \ingredient{120g Vollkorn-Weizenmehl}
  \ingredient{250g Äpfel}
  \step
  Äpfel sind auch so gesund
\end{recipe}

\begin{recipe}[]{Apfelkuchen mit Mandel-Zimt Streuseln}{}
  \par
  \ingredient{1 Päckchen Vanillezucker}
  \ingredient{2 Eier}
  \ingredient{Zimt}
  \ingredient{Salz}
  \step
  Kekse kann man auch kaufen
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

[image]